# How to insert items into specific column and row UICollectionView Cell Swift 5?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, swift5

This is sample of my data from api:

```
{
    "seats": [
        {
            "column": 0,
            "row": 0
        },
        {
            "column": 2,
            "row": 3
        },
        {
            "column": 1,
            "row": 2
        },
        {
            "column": 0,
            "row": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

My CollectionView screenshot: [default collectionView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dH9Gw.png)

My question, how to insert sample data above into specific column and row cell based on that sample data column and row?
I want to make my collectionview like following image based on that data:
[inserted items/data collectionView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ysDy.png)

Please help me..

Comment: Parse your JSON using model and use in Collection view. Please refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48670189/creating-decoration-view-as-custom-column-in-uicollection-view

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15572462/how-to-insert-cell-in-uicollectionview-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

Parse your data as array of IndexPath.

```
var apiData: [IndexPath] = []
```

In collectionView's dataSource, cellForItem(at: IndexPath), use the following code:

```
if apiData.contains(indexPath) {
  cell.alpha = 1.0
}
else {
  cell.alpha = 0.0
}
```